# Create 4 column matrix with all combinations of the 11 values from 0 to 1 increasing by 0.1.

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, python-2.7

Take the following values:

```
0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0
```

I would like to create a function which generates the 64x4 matrix, a matrix of 256 elements, that includes every set of the above eleven values for which the sum is 1

Any help regarding the most *efficient* way to do this would be very helpful.

Comment: I think [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) as used in the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) will be the way to go. Too late for thinking so hard though: this is the kind of stuff that leaves your brain sore afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

The following code does what you are after. I have used integers adding up to 10, to avoid floating point rounding errors. You could probably get it to run faster by breaking out of loops earlier, and not letting it drill all the way down before raising `StopIteration`, but it would make the code less clear.

```
def partitions(n=10, items=range(11), count=4) :
    if count == 0 and n == 0:
        yield []
    elif n < 0 or count < 0:
        raise StopIteration
    for j in xrange(len(items)) :
        ret = [items[j]]
        for k in partitions(n-items[j], items[j:], count-1) :
            yield ret + k

>>> [j for j in partitions()]
[[0, 0, 0, 10], [0, 0, 1, 9], [0, 0, 2, 8], [0, 0, 3, 7], [0, 0, 4, 6],
 [0, 0, 5, 5], [0, 1, 1, 8], [0, 1, 2, 7], [0, 1, 3, 6], [0, 1, 4, 5],
 [0, 2, 2, 6], [0, 2, 3, 5], [0, 2, 4, 4], [0, 3, 3, 4], [1, 1, 1, 7],
 [1, 1, 2, 6], [1, 1, 3, 5], [1, 1, 4, 4], [1, 2, 2, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 4], [2, 2, 3, 3]]
```

I am not very sure where did you come up with the idea that there would be 64 such subsets. The above function comes up with

```
>>> len([j for j in partitions()])
23
```

ordered subsets of 4 elements. If you don't want your subsets ordered, you can get that by calling `partitions` with the full `items`, instead of `items[j:]`in the recursive call. But then you get

```
>>> len([j for j in partitions()])
286
```

And if you don't limit yourself to subsets of 4 elements, then we have to get rid of the `0` (there are infinite subsets adding up to 10 with an arbitrary number of zeros), and then we are calculating the [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) of 10, which are [The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy), or exactly [42](http://oeis.org/A000041).

Comment: I know comments shouldn't just say thanks, but thanks, that's a brilliant answer.

Comment: @CarlSmith I know comment shouldn't just say thanks for the compliments, but thanks for the compliments!

Comment: Thanks. The 286 is what I was after. Genius answer.

Answer (score 1):

As Jaime said, Dynamic Programming will probably prove useful here. You can define this problem as a recursive search through a tree, where each node in the tree contains some of the prespecified elements. The leaves of the tree contain all combinations that sum to one.

So, on each step of your search:

1. Select the next number that does not make the sum exceed 1.
2. Add this number to your set-of-numbers-so-far, this set will be the next node.
3. Repeat from this node until you reach a leave node (sum == 1).

Once all nodes below node N have been fully explored, or N is a leave node: Go to its parent node and repeat steps 1 to 3.